# Custom event with preventDefault like functionality in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, events, preventdefault

I am facing a situation where I need to preventDefault alike functionality. the scenario is that I have written a angularjs directive using bootstrap tabs. I have exposed an closeTab event for this directive. now this is the situation when the user clicks on x icon to close tab, I raise that event (cloasTab) and in this event I would like to preventDefault (want to prevent tab from closing) so that I may be able to close tab on certain business logic. any help will be appreciated. I want to do it in javascript only

Comment: JavaScript exposes a [`preventDefault()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp) method on event objects. Might that work?

Comment: no, that is not available since this is a custom event and is raised simply by calling function name like we do in callbacks